# React Native - Access to object in array json

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, react-native

I know it's a stupid question, but I've been with this for a while and I can't solve it. I am trying to access this object which is inside an Array. Specifically to url.
I Tried this ways:

1. post.yoast_head_json.og_image.url
2. post.yoast_head_json.og_image[0].url
3. post.yoast_head_json.og_image['url']
4. post.yoast_head_json.og_image.[0].url

Doing a console.log of **post.yoast_head_json.og_image** the following comes out:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "height": 427,
    "type": "image/jpeg",
    "url": "https://www.example.es/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/pexels-picjumbocom-196656.jpg",
    "width": 640,
  },
]
```

Comment: #2 out of the ways you sent looks correct.  There may be another issue here, but that syntax matches the example.

Comment: Have you parsed your json?

Comment: No @davi-cheli-miquelim, I only made this to obtain the JSON: `    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://www.example.es/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=6')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            setPosts(response),
            setloadNews(true)
        })
      }, []);`

Comment: Try JSON.parse(your_response). save it to a variable and then you should be able to access it,, because it will transform your JSON into a javascript object

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found the solution to my problem.

Solution:

```
        let data;
        const imageUrl = [];           
        
        posts.forEach ( (post)=> {
    
        if(post.yoast_head_json.og_image != undefined)
        {
            data = JSON.stringify(post.yoast_head_json.og_image);

            JSON.parse(data, (key, value) => {  
                let valueStr = String(value);
                if (valueStr.includes('https')) {
                    imageUrl.push(valueStr);
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please explain your code, such as the changes you made to it that makes your script work.